# c++ cross compiler for beaglebone black

Tags: c++, arm, beagleboneblack, toolchain, linaro

I'm trying to compile a c++ program on windows 10 for beaglebone black by cross toolchain `gcc-linaro-5.4.1-2017.05-i686-mingw32_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz` 
and `Eclipse for DS-5 CE v 5.27.0` IDE, according to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWU31zu8x1I) on youtube.
in that video, after installation IDE and extract the toolchain and giving the toolchain's path to the IDE, I compiled a simple hello world c++ code and sent it to BBB via SSH, but here is my problem :
when I want to compile a code that uses GPIOs in my code, like this :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   std::fstream fs;

   fs.open("/sys/kernel/debug/omap_mux/gpmc_ad4");
   fs << "7";
   fs.close();
   fs.open("/sys/class/gpio/export");
   fs << "32";
   fs.close();
   fs.open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio32/direction");
   fs << "out";
   fs.close();
   fs.open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio32/value");
   fs << "1"; // "0" for off
   fs.close();
   // select whether it is on, off or flash

   return 0;
}
```

it gives me an error that says: Method 'close' could not be resolved 
and also gives this for Method 'open'.

The error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLtg2.png)

I compiled this code with Dev c++ and it worked but I want to compile it with the cross-compiler for my BBB.

please help me

Comment: When posting questions about build errors, please include the actual errors in the question body. Please edit your question to include the errors, as text, copy-pasted, in full, complete, including possible informational notes and without modifications.

Comment: And you get the errors when *building*? It's not errors from Eclipse itself? Because the Eclipse symbol database is only rebuilt when you build your application.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  when i push 'build' Button , it happend and in console window :
12:12:08 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project hi ****
make all 
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.

12:12:08 Build Finished (took 91ms)

Comment: Just a suggestion, since you are ready to dive into BeagleBoards, why not use a linux based OS ? that would make all this process much much more simpler.

Comment: @ZeekHuge   Yup, I agree with you. This is what I have to do ...